# Which race invented data crystals?

Tags: babylon-5

Data crystals are used on *Babylon 5* by pretty much every race on the station. Even the Vorlons were shown to use them when Kosh recorded Talia's mind on one in "Deathwalker", although it was created by a "Vicker" that appeared human.

But which race invented them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To my knowledge (which is considerable), it was never directly stated which race had created data crystals. However, if I had to bet, I'd put my money on the Minbari - they're known to make extensive use of crystals throughout their technology, their homeworld has large crystalline deposits, and the [Security Manual](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Babylon_5_Security_Manual) states that the best quality data crystals are made on Minbar.

As for Kosh using one, I don't think we can consider that an example of Vorlon technology - as I recall, the recording was made by Abbut, a human(ish), and the recording was meant to be used *by* humans, so it wouldn't make sense for Kosh to use some Vorlon data storage device.